# Stripe dividing by 100 in nodejs

Tags: node.js

So here is my code :

```
PaymentDaemon.authorize = function(req, callback) {
  console.log("on est dans authorize");
  console.log(req.amount);
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 3,//req.amount,
    currency: req.currency,
    source: req.card,
    description: req.details,
    capture: false
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err != null)
      console.error("ERROR in PaymentDaemon.authorize: " + err);
    else {
      req.paidDate = null;
      req.way = cfg.payment.way.in;
      req.stripe = charge.id;
      var search = {};
      if (req.payment != null)
        search._id = req.payment;
      Payment.update(search, req, { upsert: true }, function(error) {
        if (error != null) {
          console.error("ERROR in PaymentDaemon.authorize: " + err);
          console.error("ERROR Data not inserted in DB: " + JSON.stringify(req));
        }
      });
    }
    callback(err, charge);
  });
}
```

I ve put 3 because this function is called elsewhere and i am trying to find where the error come from.

here is the callling code :

```
var req = {
  amount: amount,
  currency: currency,
  card: idcard,
  details: null, // fixme
};
console.log("on est dans charge");
PaymentDaemon.authorize(req, function(error, charge) {
  if (error != null)
  {
    console.error('ERROR PaymentDaemon.createPayment() (4): ' + error);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(charge);
    res.status(200).send(charge);
  }
});
```

and when i call it, i have this error :

```
ERROR in PaymentDaemon.authorize: Error: Amount must convert to at least 50 cents. €0.03 converts to approximately $0.03.
ERROR PaymentDaemon.createPayment() (4): Error: Amount must convert to at least 50 cents. €0.03 converts to approximately $0.03.
```

So stripe seems to divide my amount by 100, any idea why ?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe expects `amount` to be set in smallest possible units. By providing `3` as value and `USD` as currency, you are basically charging $0.03.

Per their [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-amount):

> `amount` (positive integer or zero)
>
> A positive integer in the smallest currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a 0-decimal currency) representing how much to charge. The minimum amount is $0.50 US or equivalent in charge currency.